# dsm 51, assembler часы

Tags: ассемблер

хочу сделать часы для dsm-51, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что время идет, все работает, но хочу сделать редактирование времени через клавиатуру (секвенциальную, честно не помню как называется, прикрепил фото)
т.е. нажатием стрелочки вверх изменяется время на 1 значение выше, нажатие стрелочки вправо/влево, меняет объект для редактирования (часы, минуты, секунды)
прикрепил все файлы и надеюсь на помощь [image: клавиатура]

```
CSDB equ 38H    
CSDS equ 30H    
SEG0 equ P1.6   

DISP equ 79h    
SS equ 78h      
MM equ 77h      
HH equ 76h      

LIC equ 75h     
HIC equ 74h

KEYS equ 70h    

RUN bit 2Fh.7   



;============== RESTART

org 0
    ljmp start



org 0Bh                 
    mov TH0, #232
    setb F0                 
    reti



org 100h
start:

    mov DPTR, #wzory    

    mov HH, #14         
    mov MM, #39
    mov SS, #28

    acall t2d           

    ;mov DISP+6, #16        

    mov R7, #1          
    mov R0, #DISP

    mov IE, #0              

    clr TR0                 
    mov TMOD, #01000000b    
    mov TH0, #232           

    mov LIC, #176           
    mov HIC, #5

    setb RUN

    setb ET0                
    setb EA                 
    setb TR0                



mainLoop:

    jnb F0, mainLoop        
    clr F0                  





    mov R1, #CSDB       
    mov A, @R0          
    setb SEG0           
    movx @R1, A         

    mov R1, #CSDS       
    mov A, R7           
    movx @R1, A         
    clr SEG0            


                        
    jnb P3.5, noKey     
    orl KEYS, A         

noKey:
    inc R0              
    rl A                
    mov R7, A           
    jnb ACC.7, ACCnie7  
    mov R7, #1          
    mov R0, #DISP       
    mov DISP+6, KEYS    
                        
    mov A, KEYS                 
    cjne A, KEYS+1, movKeys     
    cjne A, KEYS+2, movKeys     
    cjne A, KEYS+3, servKeys    
    sjmp movKeys                

            


servKeys:
    jz movKeys              
                            
    cjne A, #2, nieEsc
    clr RUN                
nieEsc:
    cjne A, #1, nieEnter
    setb RUN                
    setb P1.7
nieEnter:

    jb RUN, movKeys
        clr P1.7







movKeys:                
    mov KEYS+3, KEYS+2  
    mov KEYS+2, KEYS+1  
    mov KEYS+1, KEYS    
    mov KEYS, #0        

ACCnie7:
    djnz LIC, mainLoop  
    djnz HIC, mainLoop



    mov LIC, #176       
    mov HIC, #5         


    jnb RUN, updTime    

    inc SS              
    mov R1, #SS
    cjne @R1, #60, updTIME
    mov SS, #0
    inc MM
    mov R1, #MM
    cjne @R1, #60, updTIME
    mov MM, #0
    inc HH
    mov R1, #HH
    cjne @R1, #24, updTIME
    mov HH, #0

updTIME:                
    acall t2d

    sjmp mainLoop       


t2d:                    
    mov A, SS           
    mov B, #10          
    div AB              
    movc A, @A+DPTR     
    mov DISP+1, A       

    mov A, B            
    movc A, @A+DPTR     
    mov DISP, A         

    mov A, MM           
    mov B, #10          
    div AB              
    movc A, @A+DPTR     
    mov DISP+3, A       

    mov A, B            
    movc A, @A+DPTR     
    mov DISP+2, A       

    mov A, HH           
    mov B, #10          
    div AB              
    movc A, @A+DPTR     
    mov DISP+5, A       

    mov A, B            
    movc A, @A+DPTR     
    mov DISP+4, A       

    ret

wzory:                  
    db 00111111b, 00000110b, 01011011b, 01001111b
    db 01100110b, 01101101b, 01111101b, 00000111b
    db 01111111b, 01101111b, 01110111b, 01111100b
    db 01011000b, 01011110b, 01111001b, 01110001b

end
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: сделать редактирование времени через клавиатуру (секвенциальную, прикрепил фото) т.е. нажатием стрелочки вверх изменяется время на 1 значение выше, нажатие стрелочки вправо/влево, меняет объект для редактирования (часы, минуты, секунды)